# Watch MongoDB Change Streams in Python asynchronous

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, changestream

How do i set up a python service that (asynchronously) watches change streams of a mongodb.

All i can find on [mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/python-change-streams/) and [pymongo docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/change_stream.html) are the following two approaches, which do not really seem production ready:

Approach mongodb.com:

```
import os
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
client = pymongo.MongoClient('<YOUR-MONGO-CONNECT-STRING>')
change_stream = client.changestream.collection.watch()
for change in change_stream:
    print(dumps(change))
```

Approach pymongo docs:

```
with db.collection.watch() as stream:
    while stream.alive:
        change = stream.try_next()
        print("Current resume token: %r" % (stream.resume_token,))
        if change is not None:
            print("Change document: %r" % (change,))
            continue
        time.sleep(10)
```

I thought about a solution using the watch function as callback for an event loop.
Does anybody know an implementation for this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in the exact same spot as you were...

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach in order to get notifications for all MongoDB updates is the following:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://YOUR-MONGO-CONNECT-STRING" % (
            mongo_user, mongo_pass, mongo_db_name))

 option={ 'full_document':'updateLookup' }

 change_stream = client.mongo_db_name.mongo_db_collection.watch([{"$match" : { "operationType" : "update" }}], **option)
 for change in change_stream:
     print(dumps(change))
     print('')
```

You will need to replace

- YOUR-MONGO-CONNECT-STRING: with your MongoDB connection URL
- mongo_user: with your username
- mongo_pass: with your password
- mongo_db_name: with the database name you wanna watch
- mongo_db_collection: with the collection name you wanna watch

Also, you can add a resume token in order to handle the cases you will e.g. have a network error. With a resume token, the stream will connect again and you will receive notifications from the point you lost the connection.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import errors

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://YOUR-MONGO-CONNECT-STRING" % (
            mongo_user, mongo_pass, mongo_db_name))

try:
    resume_token = None
    pipeline = [{'$match': {'operationType': 'update'}}]
    with client.mongo_db_name.mongo_db_collection.watch(pipeline) as stream:
        for update_change in stream:
            print(update_change)
            resume_token = stream.resume_token
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
    if resume_token is None:
       logging.error('...')
    else:
        with client.mongo_db_name.mongo_db_collection.watch(pipeline, resume_after=resume_token) as stream:
            for update_change in stream:
                print(update_change)
```